# sofia-sip-ua Library Compilation for RestComm iOS SDK

Tags: restcomm, sofia-sip

I am trying RestComm iOS SDK and stuck on Sofia-sip-ua library. Couldn't get it compiled. Please provide some help on this.

I am using the library code provided with 
https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-ios-sdk

I have Xcode 7.3 and Xcode 8 on El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally don't need to compile sofia-sip-ua library as it is already compiled for you and bundled in the [release binary](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-ios-sdk/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta.4/restcomm-ios-sdk-1.0.0-beta-4.tar.bz2) found at the GitHub [release page](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-ios-sdk/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.4). If you download it you'll find it at dependencies/packages/sofia-sip-1.12.11.

For step by step instructions on how to integrate the Restcomm iOS SDK in an iOS App (including sofia-sip-ua) please refer to the [Official Quick Start Guide](http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/sdks/restcomm-client-ios-sdk-quick-start.html#ios-sdk-guide)

Also you can check any of the working sample projects as an example [here](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-ios-sdk/tree/master/Samples)

If you still have questions, please post here again.

Best regards,
Antonis